# Is it possible to use a parameter to for a nested object property key in Cosmos DB SQL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Given objects with a nested object

```
{
  "id": "D1",
  "resourceType": "shape",
  "metadata": {
    "color": "red",
    "size": "small",
    "how heavy": "very"
  }
```

...it's possible to query them (in this case `metadata`) using the `[]` syntax by using a literal:

```
SELECT r.id, r.resourceType, r.metadata FROM Resources r WHERE r.metadata['color'] = @v1
```

Is it possible to parametrize the property access of `metadata`? The following doesn't work.

```
SELECT r.id, r.resourceType, r.metadata FROM Resources r WHERE r.metadata[@k1] = @v1
```

The preceding query produces an error

```
Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '@k1'.
```

The official docs [Parameterized queries in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-parameterized-queries) currently show only very simple examples.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm able to run this query without any problem. I am using version 3.19 of the .Net SDK.

Comment: Here's the code I wrote: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/1f6067b773b8e0daf08607767256159c.

Comment: @GauravMantri, thanks - interesting! I've simplified the object and query somewhat, so I might have lost something in translation.. :/